# Error deploying Gatsby JS site to Netlify - “Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code”

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

When I attempt to deploy my gatsby.js site to Netlify, I get the following error/failure message:

```
7:27:09 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
7:27:09 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
7:27:09 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
7:27:09 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m9.884654373s
```

I looked at [the previous question about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737661/error-running-command-build-script-returned-non-zero-exit-code-when-deploying), but I can't seem to get mine to work.

I pasted my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/mattdvhope/4849f74e392811bae069c61002b12bb8) on [JSONLine](https://jsonlint.com/) and got `Valid JSON`.

I can't seem to figure out the problem with this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `npm run build` work on your own machine?

Comment: Can you post the error that created the exit code further up in your build log?

Comment: You'd need to give more details to get the best answer.  All of those lines are the SYMPTOM for the failure, not the cause.  The cause is further up (whatever causes the build process to exit with a status code of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all empty directories are going into your repository. There may be a missing path with reference to a missing directory in your repository.

example plugin in `gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/img`,
    name: `images`,
  },
}
```

A common mistake is to add `src/img` to your local file system, but forget to commit it into your repository until you get images.

Answer (score 1):

tldr; add a `.gitkeep` file to your `src/images` folder if it is empty.

I encountered this same issue. Building locally worked, but deploying to Netlify failed for unknown reasons.

Turns out, the issue happened because I deleted the placeholder Gatsby images from `src/images`.

When I deleted the images, the folder was empty. Git ignores empty folders, so the next time I pushed to my remote repo, the `src/images` folder was removed.

But my `gatsby-config` file referenced `src/images`. That folder still existed when I ran `build` locally, but not in the remote version that Netlify was trying to deploy.

Anyway, adding a `.gitkeep` file to the `src/images` directory fixed the problem. `.gitkeep` tells Git to keep the directory (even though it's empty), which meant that Netlify was not trying to access a directory that did not exist.