# ViewChild is undefined in angular 13

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular13

I am trying to call view child of a child component from parent and getting undefined in the console.

see the image also see the [stack blaze](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4m2hp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for the same

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4m2hp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

[image: see the image also see the stack blaze for the same]

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TestChildComponent } from './test-child/test-child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>this is Hello component {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
@ViewChild('TestChildComponent') testChildComponent: TestChildComponent
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('calling ngOninit in hello component');
    console.log('going to call test child instance this.TestChildComponent.ngOninit')
   console.log(this.testChildComponent);
  }
}
```

Please help to get the child component

> this.testChildComponent

So that i can call ngOnInit of child from parent.

> this.testChildComponent.ngOnInit()

Comment: try using ngAfterViewInit() method instead of ngOnInit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set your viewChild { static: true } you will be able to access it in ngOnInit

but in your sample the issue is due totestChildComponent is a child of app.component and not hello.component

```
<app-test-child childname="{{ name }}" #test></app-test-child>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TestChildComponent } from './test-child/test-child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'this is from app compoenent';
  @ViewChild('test', { static: true }) testChildComponent: TestChildComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('calling ngOninit in app component');
    console.log(this.testChildComponent);
  }
}
```

If you want to access testChildComponent from hello.component you will have to send it the component as an input for sample

following a working sample of accessing testChildComponent

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tvwukg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks , but in my orignal project (not stackbalze ) in client location , i am getting static:true

Comment: argument of type static boolean is not assignable to parameter of type read any

Comment: Do you identify your <app-test-child childname> tag with same id pass to view child ?
I don't see this error in the stackblitz above

Comment: yes in stackbliz i am not getting that error

Comment: which version of angular core are you using ?

Comment: I also found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551378/argument-of-type-static-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-r

Comment: angular 8i am using

Comment: Once you upgraded to newer version of Angular. Remove node_module folder and run npm install

Comment: i am trying this now

Comment: error is gone after Once you upgraded to newer version of Angular. Remove node_module folder and run npm install this change , thanks

Comment: there are multiple other issue, will let you know

Answer (score 4):

ViewChild element ref can be accessed in `ngAfterViewInit()` cycle the earliest.

[image]

Angular doc says we should use the child component injected by ViewChild in ngAfterViewInit. But sometimes you even can’t get it in ngAfterViewInit. The reason is, the child component is not created yet when AfterViewInit hook runs. For such a case you would have to wait more (using a `setTimeout` would work but it's a bad idea). Other option would be to have the child emit something to the parent, letting it know the child has been rendered and then the parent can query it.

But your case is that sibling `HelloComponent` wants to query sibling `TestChildComponent` it can't do that. `TestChildComponent` is just not in the scope for `HelloComponent`. Easiest solution would be to query `TestChildComponent` from the parent `AppComponent`.

You should also add `#TestChildComponent` to access the ref.

```html
<app-test-child #TestChildComponent childname="{{ name }}"></app-test-child>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5ceat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

If `ViewChild` is undefined in the parent component, it's possible that the child component hasn't been rendered yet.

To make sure that the child component has been rendered before using ViewChild, you can implement the `ngAfterViewInit` in your parent component.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child></app-child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent!: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was my issue because I was toggling the visibility using ngif. I had to hook into ngInit, in order to update the component after making visible. Any other life cycle hook would cause issues with bound data.