# Why does removing package-lock.json break a build, but running "npm install" without deleting it doesn't?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a project where I removed some no-longer needed libraries from my `package.json` file, removed `node_modules`, ran `npm install`, and everything continued to work as expected.

Unfortunately if I follow the same steps above *after having deleted `package-lock.json`*, my build suddenly breaks. A new `package-lock.json` is generated but I now get hundreds of deprecation warnings from some dependencies and even though the project continues to build those same dependencies will break in unexpected places.

If I revert to the previous `package-lock.json` and again run the same steps (remove `node_modules`, run `npm install`), the warnings once again disappear and the build is once more in a safe state.

My understanding is that `package-lock.json` will update every time we run `npm install` with the most recent package versions, respecting the caret`^` and tilde`~` restrictions. Does this update differ if we have an existing `package-lock.json` vs a fresh install?

Even if there is somehow a conflict between sub-dependencies I'm still confused why updating a `package-lock.json` with `npm install` works great but running `npm install` after deleting that file creates a new `package-lock.json` that breaks. This happens consistently over many attempts.

Comment: Don't delete `package-lock.json`? Modern node+npm uses `package.json` to determine which dependency version ranges are permitted, and `package-lock.json` to determine which _actual versions_ should be used (especially due to security issues in older versions of dependencies). If you're seeing lots of warnings: read the warnings. There's different kinds, and without saying what you're seeing, there's not much we can say about them other than "peg versions you need pegged, and run `npm audit fix` to make sure any insecure dependency is uplifted to a secure version".

Comment: With package-lock.json still available npm install will install the packages in exactly the versions that are specified in the package-lock.json. if you remove it, some packages may be installed in newer versions, which may break dependencies

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks for the response, but my understanding is that since npm v5.1.0 `npm install` *will not* install the packages inside package-lock.json. From that version on we need to do `npm ci` for that behavior. That is why I'm confused about what's going on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same confusion with my own repo.

So I'm writing this my own sake as much as yours, in the hopes I remember it for next time I come looking for a solution.

**The update on [this npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979#issuecomment-332701215) clarified everything for me:**

> 1. If you have a `package.json` and you run `npm i` we generate a
>    `package-lock.json` from it.
> 2. If you run `npm i` against that `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, the latter will never be updated, even if the `package.json` would be
>    happy with newer versions.
> 3. If you manually edit your `package.json` to have different ranges and
>    run `npm i` and those ranges aren't compatible with your `package- lock.json` then the latter will be updated with version that are
>    compatible with your `package.json`. Further runs of `npm i` will be as
>    with 2 above.

**And here is an explanation on what was happening with your case:**

> I have a project where I removed some no-longer needed libraries from
> my package.json file, removed node_modules, ran npm install, and
> everything continued to work as expected.

In this case it was doing step 2 from above. You have a working `package-lock.json` in place with all the correct dependency versions. So it reinstalled based on `package-lock.json`. It did not edit `package-lock.json` even if your `package.json` says it would be happy with newer versions.

> Unfortunately if I follow the same steps above after having deleted
> package-lock.json, my build suddenly breaks. A new package-lock.json
> is generated but I now get hundreds of deprecation warnings from some
> dependencies and even though the project continues to build those same
> dependencies will break in unexpected places.

In this case it is doing step 1 from above. No `package-lock.json` was found, so it recreated your project from `package.json`, updating to newer versions as your `package.json` would allow. It then generated a new `package-lock.json` based on that install. Unfortunately for you, those updated versions broke your project.

> If I revert to the previous package-lock.json and again run the same
> steps (remove node_modules, run npm install), the warnings once again
> disappear and the build is once more in a safe state.

This is essentially doing the same thing as before. It is doing step 2 from above. Since you once again have a working `package-lock.json` with all the correct package versions it will reinstall based on `package-lock.json`. It does not edit `package-lock.json` even if your `package.json` says it would be happy with newer versions. This is why it worked again, because none of the packages were upgraded to the problematic version.

> My understanding is that package-lock.json will update every time we
> run npm install with the most recent package versions, respecting the
> caret^ and tilde~ restrictions. Does this update differ if we have an
> existing package-lock.json vs a fresh install?

Yes this will differ as described in the steps above. If you have an existing `package-lock.json` it will respect and install those exact package versions. If you're doing a fresh install it will update to newer (and potentially breaking) versions as are allowed in `package.json`.

This is why `package-lock.json` should be committed to version control and never deleted. The [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json) also recommend that.

There might be times where you are tempted to delete `package-lock.json` to solve conflicts. That is a bad idea, as explained in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly). Instead, you can manually make changes to `package.json` and then run `npm install`. That is like doing step 3 above. Alternatively you can do `npm update {dependency}` or `npm install {dependency}@2.1.3` which has the same effect.