# npm failed to execute error in a react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have deleted **.lock** file and **node_modules** and tried to install again. However, it isn't working.
Could you help me to fix?

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=J:\React Projects\react-context-lesson\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=J:\React Projects\react-context-lesson\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v93-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (J:\React Projects\react-context-lesson\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "J:\\React Projects\\reacnpm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd J:\React Projects\react-context-lesson\node_modules\grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54124033/14858924

Comment: Does your PC username have a space (" ") in it ? It can cause unexpected problems in Node. It can be bypassed by running cmd as admin.

Comment: It has space. How can I remove the space from name

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be something with the version of Node. Can you try with version 14?

Comment: all other projects works smoothly in this version.

Comment: Node 16 is the current LTS version (Dec 2021). I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: I am using node 16