# npm Err! code E401, Incorrect or missing password

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Everyone
When I was trying to install node modules using npm install facing issue. I removed package.lock.json file but still facing issue

npm ERR! code E401

npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.

npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.

npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:

npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 3):

Finally resolved my issue asper getting Incorrect password or missing Info.
This is related missing Info along with credentials or else asper authentication rules. If you got access from some other npm related packages you must assign and give the credentials

Try Deleting the package-lock.json file before running the command "npm install" after upgrading the node versions, if you have not done that.

If that will not work try removing the .npmrc file in $HOME directory as mentioned in this post.
[Deleting `package-lock.json` to Resolve Conflicts quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124033/deleting-package-lock-json-to-resolve-conflicts-quickly?noredirect=1&lq=1)