# Vercel - E401 Incorrect or missing password

Tags: npm, next.js, npm-install, vercel

I have a Next.js project hosted in Vercel that is connected to my Bitbucket repository. But just recently, I have been experiencing this build issue with Vercel:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-01-03T21_52_49_050Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I don't use any private NPM packages, and the builds were working in the past week. No new NPM packages were added at all, which is why I find this issue strange.

When doing `vercel build` via the Vercel CLI this error does not happen as well. It only happens when the build is done in the Vercel portal.

I have tried deleting and regenerating my `package-lock.json` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230271/2279976), but still no luck.