# Error: require() of ES Module when trying to run a node container

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to build my angular app using a Github Action. I got some errors in the action that are caused by the container used.
Now I build a basic local container trying to run the linter as a first step.

**Dockerfile**

```yaml
FROM node:18.18

COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn lint
```

If I try to build the container, I run into the following error:

```bash
Node.js v18.18.0"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
error /node_modules/@parcel/watcher: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp-build
Arguments:
Directory: /node_modules/@parcel/watcher
Output:
/node_modules/wide-align/align.js:2
var stringWidth = require('string-width')
                  ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /node_modules/string-width/index.js from /node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/wide-align/align.js:2:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/gauge/lib/render-template.js:2:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/gauge/lib/plumbing.js:3:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/gauge/lib/index.js:2:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/npmlog/lib/log.js:3:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:5:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js:8:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Some dependency is using `require()` instead of `import`, so the build of the container fails. Does anyone have a fix for that? I tried different node versions and images like bitnami/node, but the issue still exists. Somehow the error also only occurs when running a container. From my local node version the lint, test, build steps, all work fine.

Comment: It's not the node versions that is the problem. You're trying different versions of the wrong thing. It's the version of `string-width` that is the problem. Try different (older) versions of `string-width`

Comment: yes, but its a peer dependencie of some other package. Isn't it bad behavior to tinker around in the yarn.lock?

Comment: If it's a peer dependency then it means you have control of which version is installed

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question above, isn't it bad behavior to change stuff in my yarn.lock?

Comment: There is a known issue with that dependency, that hasn't been updated yet. The workaround is removing the yarn.lock from the repo.
See: https://github.com/iarna/wide-align/issues/63

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If someone in the future should have the same problem:
There is a known issue with that dependency, that hasn't been updated yet. The workaround is removing the yarn.lock from the repo. See: [github.com/iarna/wide-align/issues/63](https://github.com/iarna/wide-align/issues/63)

**Update:**

As stated by multiple people in the issue, adding this to your package.json should also resolve the issue:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "string-width": "4.2.3"
 }
```

Resolutions is a yarn feature, for npm use

```json
 "overrides": {
     "string-width": "4.2.3"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using a recent and more stable version of Yarn. I'm using 3.6.4 and was able to build the docker image of my NestJS app without any problems.
In a powershell terminal inside your project folder, you just need to run this command: yarn set version 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add this code inside package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "jackspeak": "2.1.1"
 }
```

1. Remove node_modules folder and yarn.lock package.lock files.
2. Run npm/yarn install.

Worked for me :)

Comment: God bless you man, the deletion `yarn.lock` after adding resolutions is what resolved it for me after hours of searching online

Comment: There's no such thing as `resolutions` if you use npm and not yarn. Use `overrides` if your project utilises npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json.

Also deleting `yarn.lock`/ `package-lock.json` can be dangerous if you don't know what you are doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127283/102397